# Is there a way to run the ObjectAid Sequence Diagram Eclipse plugin despite the site being closed?

Tags: java, eclipse, sequence-diagram, objectaid

Related to the question "ObjectAid homepage is no longer accessible", the solution given which involves installing from the archive did not work for me since the license validation process still tries to run. My license keys are in place, but with the ObjectAid site being down, re-validation is not possible and thus the plugin does not function.

Has anybody had success at continuing to run the ObjectAid Sequence Diagram plugin for Eclipse despite the site being down? If so, can you share your solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I install a free version from this archive? Where is the archive?

Comment: I couldn't agree more about how useful ObjectAid was. Ever since it's disappearance, I have not been able to create sequence diagrams. I have not yet found anything that comes close to its ease of use. The archive I was using was left-over from when ObjectAid was still available and I no longer have it nor do I know where you would be able to obtain it now. Meanwhile, I just discovered this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589918/objectaid-unhandled-event-loop-exception - perhaps this will be of some help? I'll be trying this myself later. Hopefully it works! Good luck.

Comment: In that answer is explained how to fix it if you already have the ObjectAid jar which I don't have. But I've found from where to download an old version and how to install it. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696763/how-to-install-objectaid-in-2022/71720676

Comment: Does anyone has any way to know what happened?

I was able to find these pages 

https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/BusinessSearch/BusinessInformation?businessId=1591528&businessType=Domestic%20Limited%20Liability%20Company&fromSearch=True

https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_ga/11007056 

which says the company is "Status Admin. Dissolved" as of 09/30/2021

There is an agent name mentioned, "Felix Mayer", is anyone in US able to contact this agent and inquiry what happened?

People (like me) still have paid licenses which I can't install anymore on new computers...

Answer (score 1):

It *appears* that ObjectAid LLC has gone out of business.  Their website has gone offline, and the DNS name "objectaid.com" is currently "parked" at GoDaddy.

(For people who want to find the old website, check [here](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://objectaid.com).)

However:

1. We don't **know** that they have gone out of business.  Someone might have simply forgotten to pay the bill for their DNS entries.
2. Even if they have gone out of business, *someone* still owns the IP rights for the software that ObjectAid LLC has developed, and *someone* probably still owns ObjectAid LLC's rights in any contracts with their users.

   The "someone" might be the original owners of the company, the company's creditors, or some other company that is taking them over / buying them out.  Those people may still have ideas of monetizing the remaining assets.
3. If you were to attempt to develop a work-around for their license management system being off-line, that would *probably* entail reverse engineering the software, which is *probably* a violation of the terms of your license with ObjectAid LLC.  That may place you at legal risk.
4. If you ... or someone else were to *publish* details of a work-around, that could be illegal depending on where you are.
5. Just using such an work-around *could* be illegal, depending on where you are.
6. If Stack Overflow were to (knowingly) publish an Answer containing a work-around, then Stack Exchange would potentially be liable for damages.  And since they most likely have "deeper pockets" than you do, Stack Exchange would likely be the primary target for (hypothetical) lawsuits aimed at getting a payout.

<sup>None of the above should be read as legal advice.  If you feel you need something more definitive: 1) read the fine print of your license, and 2) talk to a professional lawyer.</sup>

---

My advice would be: don't develop a work-around.  And if you do develop one, or find one, don't share the details here.

Instead, start looking for an alternative to this plugin.

---

<sup>For the record: 1) I don't know of a work-around, and 2) I don't know of an alternative.</sup>

Comment: I was a paying customer and ObjectAid invoices are emitted by "ObjectAid LLC Atlanta, GA USA". 
The business is dissolved as reported in https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/BusinessSearch/BusinessInformation?businessId=1591528&businessType=Domestic%20Limited%20Liability%20Company&fromSearch=True 

The website has an agent name, Felix Mayer.

There is a solution architect named Felix Mayer in Atlanta on Linked In
https://www.linkedin.com/in/felix-lj-mayer/

I fear something bad happened for such sudden disappearance...

Comment: I confirm the LinkedIn profile is the Felix Mayer of object aid, the contact info in LinkedIn mention the website: https://www.linkedin.com/in/felix-lj-mayer/overlay/contact-info/