# How to Install ObjectAid in 2022?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, class-diagram, objectaid

**ObjectAid** was a very useful [Eclipse plug-in](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/objectaid-uml-explorer) which generates **class diagram** from your source code.

Unfortunately it looks like it is discontinued in March 2022 or at least [its website](https://www.objectaid.com) is not working.

### Can anyone tell me from where to download and install it?

[image]

Comment: Nobody knows what happened? Its marketplace is available but the website is gone?
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/objectaid-uml-explorer

Comment: Does anyone has any way to know what happened?

I was able to find these pages 

https://ecorp.sos.ga.gov/BusinessSearch/BusinessInformation?businessId=1591528&businessType=Domestic%20Limited%20Liability%20Company&fromSearch=True

https://opencorporates.com/companies/us_ga/11007056 

which says the company is "Status Admin. Dissolved" as of 09/30/2021

There is an agent name mentioned, "Felix Mayer", is anyone in US able to contact this agent and inquiry what happened?

People (like me) still have paid licenses which I can't install anymore on new computers...

Comment: I confirm the LinkedIn profile is the Felix Mayer of object aid, the contact info in LinkedIn mention the website: https://www.linkedin.com/in/felix-lj-mayer/overlay/contact-info/

Comment: Sad news, I think the author of ObjectAid was killed in a accident https://www.mdjonline.com/neighbor_newspapers/northside_sandy_springs/news/sandy-springs-police-arrest-suspect-accused-of-killing-bicyclist-in-hit-and-run-case/article_ad23098e-889b-11ea-8b6b-c7acd8377384.html

:-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been able to install an old version of ObjectAid. Here is what I did:

1. I downloaded **objectaid-1.1.14.zip** from [ObjectAid on web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20190113065017/http://www.objectaid.com/download) 2019-Jan-13

[image: ObjecAid download page on web.archive.org]

2. ...[OpenJDK 7](https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk7u75/ri/openjdk-7u75-b13-linux-x64-18_dec_2014.tar.gz)
3. ...and [Eclipse Juno 4.2.2](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2)
4. An Eclipse plug-in called [Draw2D](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/download.php?file=/tools/gef/downloads/drops/legacy/4.0.0/R201606061308/GEF3-Update-4.0.0.zip) was also needed.
5. Then I installed only ObjecdAid Class Diagram for which **license is not required**.

[image: Installing old version of ObjecAid]

### Update

You can also download [version 1.2.4](http://web.archive.org/web/20210111132410/https://www.objectaid.com/download) which works with **Java 17** and **Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0)** but then you must follow the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70785096/11886026) to be able to run it.

Comment: your update does not work in Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0). Missing requirement: Apache Batik AWT Utilities 1.6.0.v201011041432 (org.apache.batik.ext.awt 1.6.0.v201011041432) requires 'osgi.bundle;

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions from the linked answer? It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a solution as it would last only until the hosting tear it down, but...

The objectaid.com website is actually still there: it's just the DNS that is gone.

You can open the website adding its old IP to your /etc/hosts file:

```
208.95.104.30 objectaid.com
```

The site is fully working, I can login and manage my licenses:

[image]

If you have a license, you may try to change it to an offline license with this trick.

P.S. If you didn't see my comments to other questions, the author of ObjectAid, [Felix Mayer](https://www.linkedin.com/in/felix-lj-mayer/overlay/contact-info/) was sadly killed in a accident https://www.mdjonline.com/neighbor_newspapers/northside_sandy_springs/news/sandy-springs-police-arrest-suspect-accused-of-killing-bicyclist-in-hit-and-run-case/article_ad23098e-889b-11ea-8b6b-c7acd8377384.html, website was left orphan and DNS name expired :-(

Comment: For those in the EU blocked from viewing the article, here is a snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20200512112452/https://www.mdjonline.com/neighbor_newspapers/northside_sandy_springs/news/sandy-springs-police-arrest-suspect-accused-of-killing-bicyclist-in-hit-and-run-case/article_ad23098e-889b-11ea-8b6b-c7acd8377384.html

Comment: Thank you, any idea why they'd block that ??