# I can't finish creating uml class diagram with object aid, do you know how to fix it?

Tags: objectaid

If i click on finish it doesn't do nothing, can you help me with this problem ?[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxmTK.png)

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAid is not maintained anymore and this results in exactly as you asked in the question. The solution which worked for me is to either downgrade to Java 11 from Java 17 or apply the solution explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589918/objectaid-unhandled-event-loop-exception).Its not mentioned but I may like to clarify that this happened when you try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtSRX9swc1w).