# Eclipse 2023-03 crashes with old eclipse.ini +UseZGC

Tags: eclipse, vmargs

When running eclipse 2023-03 with old eclipse.ini (or after upgrading 2022-03) eclipse doesn't start anymore and nothing is found in workspace/.metadata/log, or in console.

The old `eclipse.ini` had the following vmargs that worked

```
-vmargs
-XX:+UseZGC
-javaagent:lombok-1.18.26--withMapstruct-1.4.2.Final.jar
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:+AlwaysPreTouch
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:ZAllocationSpikeTolerance=1
-XX:InitialHeapSize=6G
-XX:MaxRAM=6G
-XX:MaxHeapSize=6G
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1G
--illegal-access=permit
#for objectaid - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68589918/objectaid-unhandled-event-loop-exception/70785096#70785096
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=17
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.reportNonDisposed=true
-Dsun.java.command=Eclipse
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: There are no comments in the `eclipse.ini`. Also the line starting with `#` is passed to the VM, which can cause issues.

Comment: Oh. I will test. The thing is the 2022-03 eclipse was able to start with this ini file.

Comment: Probably the Java VM crashed with the VM arguments you specified, even before Eclipse could be started as a Java application. Which Java VM did you use in each case? The `eclipse.ini` of 2023-03 vs. 2022-03 differ at least in the value of `--launcher.library`. So you cannot use your old `eclipse.ini` from 2022-03 for 2023-03.

Answer (score 0):

Having two `-XX:+UseZGC` and `-XX:+UseG1GC` had conflicts that before where ignored but now do not work anymore.

Test by yourself directly on jvm

```
λ java -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseZGC
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Multiple garbage collectors selected
```